# Map task stuck at 50%

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a mapper and reducer classes with input and output values as set below.

```
//Reducer
job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(MapperOutput.class);

//Mapper
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(MapperOutput.class);
```

Here `MapperOutput` is a custom class defined by me and it implements `Writable` interface.

A part of my mapper function is as below.

```
public void map(LongWritable arg0, Text arg1,
        Context context)
        throws IOException 
{
    try
    {
        String tran = null;
        String ip = arg1.toString();
        System.out.println(ip);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(ip));
        Hsynopsis bdelta = null;
        Hsynopsis b = null, bnew = null;

        hashEntries = (int) Math.floor(calculateHashEntries()); //Hash table size
        System.out.println("Hash entries: "+hashEntries);

        //Initialize the main hash table and delta hashtable
        hashTable = new ArrayList<>(hashEntries);
        for(int i = 0; i < hashEntries; i++)
        {
            hashTable.add(i, null);
        }

        deltahashTable = new ArrayList<>(hashEntries);  
        for(int i = 0; i < hashEntries; i++)
        {
            deltahashTable.add(i, null);
        }

        while((tran = br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            createBinaryRep(tran);
            for(int i = 0; i < deltahashTable.size(); i++)
            {
                bdelta = deltahashTable.get(i);
                if(bdelta != null)
                {
                    if(bdelta.NLast_Access >= (alpha * transactionCount))
                    {
                        //Transmit bdelta to the coordinator
                        MapperOutput mp = new MapperOutput(transactionCount, bdelta);
                        context.write(new LongWritable(i), mp);

                        //Merge bdelta into b
                        b = hashTable.get(i);
                        bnew = merge(b,bdelta);
                        hashTable.set(i, bnew);

                        //Release bdelta
                        deltahashTable.set(i, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

My reducer task is as below.

```
public void reduce(LongWritable index, Iterator<MapperOutput> mpValues, Context context)
{
    while(mpValues.hasNext())
    {
        /*Some code here */
    }

    context.write(index, mp);
}
```

From the code of mapper, as the algorithm demands, I am trying to send output to the reducer as and when the `condition is satisfied` (inside the `for` loop), and the mapper after writing to the `context`, continues to execute the loop.

When I try to run this code on a single-node Hadoop cluster, I get the following log.

```
15/04/29 03:19:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/04/29 03:19:23 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
15/04/29 03:19:23 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
15/04/29 03:19:23 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
15/04/29 03:19:23 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
15/04/29 03:19:24 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local599819429_0001
15/04/29 03:19:24 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
15/04/29 03:19:24 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local599819429_0001_m_000000_0
15/04/29 03:19:24 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code     0
15/04/29 03:19:24 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@74ff364a
15/04/29 03:19:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/pooja/ADM/FrequentPatternMining/input/file.dat~:0+24
15/04/29 03:19:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
15/04/29 03:19:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
15/04/29 03:19:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
15/04/29 03:19:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
15/04/29 03:19:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
15/04/29 03:19:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/04/29 03:19:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
15/04/29 03:19:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
```

The map task has stuck at 50% and doesn't proceed.

When I run the map function separately (not in Hadoop), I am not having any problem of an infinite loop.

Can anyone please me with this?

Edit 1: My input file is in the orders of KB. Is that causing a problem for the distribution of data to mappers?

Edit 2: As mentioned in the answer, I changed Iterator to Iterable. Still the map gets stuck at 100% and after some time it restarts.

I could see the following in jobtracker log:

```
2015-04-29 13:26:28,026 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskInProgress: Error from attempt_201504291300_0003_m_000000_0: Task attempt_201504291300_0003_m_000000_0 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
2015-04-29 13:26:28,026 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Removing task 'attempt_201504291300_0003_m_000000_0'
```

Comment: test your code using MR unit test case. I think that will help to find bugs in code ... If you can update complete map method then we could have a look

Comment: Just to clarify, MapperOutput class has implemented writable class ??

Comment: @VenkataKarthik Yes, it has. I have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @VenkataKarthik I have implemented the Writable interface but have not overridden the function public void readFields(DataInput arg0) and public void write(DataOutput arg0). Should that be done? Is that creating a problem?

Comment: if you have not overridden the function then how serialization and deserialzation would take place

Comment: @Pooja N Babu you have to overwrite both read and write methods.  I think that should solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakenly used **iterator** in reduce function  instead of iterable .

You need to use iterable as you are using new map reduce API's, because 
 reduce(Object, Iterable, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context)

method is called for each  in the sorted inputs.

Comment: I changed it to Iterable but still the map is stuck at 100%. I have updated the question with JobTracker logs. Please have a look.

Comment: can you please try increasing the time out parameter in mapred-site.xml
<property>
  <name>mapred.task.timeout</name>
  <value>1800000</value> <!-- 30 minutes -->
</property>

Comment: I changed the timeout to 120000 (1200 seconds) but still got this log. `Task attempt_201504291345_0001_m_000000_0 failed to report status for 1200 `

Comment: Does the namenode require to be reformatted after changing a config value?

Comment: Did you restart the job tracker and task tracker ?

Comment: Yes have restarted them.

Comment: can you please try a simple word count program to test whether that is working for you or not , just to check whether problem in code or cluster ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76520/discussion-between-pooja-n-babu-and-user3484461).

Answer (score 0):

It happens some time if your code gets stuck in infinite loop. Try checking for that.